# How to insert a secret in alertmanager configuration file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I provisioned alertmanager using Helm (and ArgoCD).
I need to insert smtp_auth_password value but not as a plain text.

```
smtp_auth_username: 'apikey'
smtp_auth_password: $API_KEY
```

How can I achieve it? I heard about "external secret" but this should be the easiest way?

Comment: AlertManager configuration is often completely written into a secret. Beyond those settings you point out, several integrations would also involve including secret data (opsgenie, slack, webhook bearer tokens in general). Unless you have a sidecar rewriting your conf during startup, I don't think we can read those from another file or environment variables: you'ld better write your whole alertmanager config into a secret

Comment: I already have a secret which include the api key of our smtp in my cluster. It means that I can't use it? For example, I know that in Grafana I can do something like: 
smtp_auth_password: $__file{/etc/secrets/secretName/KEY}. 
If this is not an option, how can I use a new conf file?

Comment: you would probably have to use an initContainer, generating alertmanager final configuration from some sort of template, setting in values from your secrets, before alertmanager starts up

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

if you use `prometheus-community/prometheus` which includes this alertmanager [chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/alertmanager) as a dependency, then you can do the following:

**create secret** in the same namespace where your alertmanager pod is running:

```bash
k create secret generic alertmanager-secrets \
  --from-literal="opsgenie-api-key=YOUR-OPSGENIE-API-KEY" \
  --from-literal="slack-api-url=https://hooks.slack.com/services/X03R2856W/A14T19TKEGM/...."
```

**mount that secret** via use of extraSecretMounts

```yaml
alertmanager:
  enabled: true
  service:
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"  
  # contains secret values for opsgenie and slack receivers
  extraSecretMounts:
    - name: secret-files
      mountPath: /etc/secrets
      subPath: ""
      secretName: alertmanager-secrets
      readOnly: true
```

**use them in your receivers**:

```yaml
receivers:
  - name: slack-channel
    slack_configs:
      - channel: '#client-ccf-ccl-alarms'
        api_url_file: /etc/secrets/slack-api-url <-------------------THIS
        title: '{{ template "default.title" . }}'
        text: '{{ template "default.description" . }}'
        pretext: '{{ template "slack.pretext" . }}'
        color: '{{ template "slack.color" . }}'
        footer: '{{ template "slack.footer" . }}'
        send_resolved: true
        actions:
          - type: button
            text: "Query :mag:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_query_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Silence :no_bell:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_silencer_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Karma UI :mag:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_karma_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Runbook :green_book:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_runbook_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Grafana :chart_with_upwards_trend:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_grafana_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "KB :mag:"
            url: '{{ template "alert_kb_url" . }}'

  - name: opsgenie
    opsgenie_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        api_key_file: /etc/secrets/opsgenie-api-key <-------------------THIS
        message: '{{ template "default.title" . }}'
        description: '{{ template "default.description" . }}'
        source: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.source" . }}'
        priority: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.priority" . }}'
        tags: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.tags" . }}'
```

If you want to use email functionality of [email_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#email_config)
then simply use the same approach with:

```
[ auth_password_file: <string> | default = global.smtp_auth_password_file ]
```

Comment: NICE ONE DUDE! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If using `kube_prometheus_stack` where it doesn't support the `extraSecretMounts`, you can use `alertmanager.alertmanagerSpec.secrets` instead;

```
alertmanager:
  alertmanagerSpec:
    secrets:
      - alertmanager-secrets
```

Then use it with a different path value in the receivers:

```
    receivers:
    - name: 'slack.backend'
      slack_configs:
      - api_url_file: /etc/alertmanager/secrets/alertmanager-secrets/slack-api-url
```

Comment: definitely the solution i was looking for.